# How to access Form field data passed at init in QuerySelectField of another field

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have this code:

in **route.py**:

```
@app.route('/task/<param_userid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def task_new(param_userid=None):
    ...
    obj_task_new = {'user_id': param_userid}
    form = FormTask(**obj_task_new)
    ...
```

in **forms.py**:

```
class FormTask(Form):
    user_id = fields.TextField('UID',validators=[validators.required()])
    group = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: db.session.query([MODEL]).filter_by(user_id_field=[USER_ID]), allow_blank=False)
    ...
```

where **[MODEL]** is a **db.Model** class (don't think it's relevant here)

---

What I need is the **[USER_ID]** value dynamically passed from the **user_id** which I am sending via **obj_task_new** in **route.py**

---

I also tried with

```
 QuerySelectField(query_factory=CustomFunction,...
```

But I found no way to pass a parameter to it and even if I did find a way to pass parameters the issue with accessing the **user_id** value still remains.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can set the query on the field at runtime in your controller:

   ```
   form = FormTask(**obj_task_new)
   form.group.query = db.session.query([MODEL]).filter_by(user_id_field=[param_userid]), allow_blank=False)
   ```
2. You can take advantage of the fact that `request` is a thread-local and use that in your custom function:

   ```
   def for_current_user():
       user_id = request.view_args.get('param_userid')
       return db.session.query([MODEL]).filter_by(...)

   # And then in your form definition
   QuerySelectField(query_factory=for_current_user)
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much, both options work.

I had the same idea with the request at one point but I guess I did not implement it properly (if I did it would have saved me long hours of searching...)